# Can I import characters?

Tags: import

I’m just getting started with Blender, and I’d like to know something in advance: can I import a character from Reallusion Character Creator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import models from another program, you basically must find a “common language” format that has all the data you need, such as armatures and texture maps, and is writable/readable by both programs. Blender has many default-enabled import addons, and a few more which are not enabled by default but come with blender, and still more third-party addons around the web. You can usually see what can be imported in the File -> Import menu.

So, what formats can Reallusion Character Creator export to? I recommend Collada .DAE if that’s available as it is Blender’s preferred import/export format.

Comment: I tested out the pipeline between cc3 and blender recently.  Unfortunately, there isn't an option for automatically generating a rig for the weighted skeleton that cc exports. 
A  MakeHuman addon  can set up a rigify rig automatically on import, but MH models are not as appealing.  The same feature from CharacterCreator would be a real timesaver.